# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS: Update python 2.7.3 to 2.7.6 without breaking dependencies

Tags: python, linux, ubuntu, python-2.7

So, I recently reinstalled Precise after encountering some swap issues.  A friend and I were discussing working on something in Python together, so I checked my version.  However, 12.04 comes with Python 2.7.3 installed.  I wanted to update to 2.7.6, so I downloaded the tar for it.  Then, I was silly enough to punch in `sudo apt-get remove python` without considering the dependency issues for my desktop.  (My rationale was that I wanted to get rid of the old install.)

Long story short, I broke all of my Python dependencies, thus destroying Unity.  I just finished re-installing Ubuntu again.

I tried following [this tutorial](http://www.linuxfromscratch.org/blfs/view/svn/general/python2.html), but

1. `make test` had about a 50% failure rate (a separate concern in itself)
2. When I entered

   > make install &&
   >   chmod -v 755 /usr/lib/libpython2.7.so.1.0

I got

```
/usr/bin/install -c python /usr/bin/python2.7
/usr/bin/install: cannot remove `/usr/bin/python2.7': Permission denied
make: *** [altbininstall] Error 1
```

I'm concerned, as a result, that running the command again as root would result in removing 2.7.3 all over again.  I'm anything but a bash guru, so I don't have a good sense for what's going under the hood here.  I'm just trying to get 2.7.6 at this point; I'm perfectly content with 2.7.3 staying on the machine if there are dependencies.

So, should I...

A. just run the command as root?

B. update Python some other way (and by "update" I really just mean get a clean install of 2.7.6)? If so, how?

Comment: How did you manage to `apt-get remove python` without it warning you about dependencies?

Comment: @WaleedKhan Perhaps it did, and I just missed it.  I am not a professional, or even remotely informed when it comes to these things.    I'm learning by trial and error on a spare laptop, not my primary machine, so blowing things up isn't all that bothersome.  I do try to make a point of looking further into this sort of thing in advance; this was an unfortunate exception.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a "have your cake and eat it" problem:

- *Either* you value the stability of Ubuntu 12.04 LTS,
- *or* you value current versions.

I tend to upgrade every six months.  There can be hybrids; maybe there is a PPA with "backported" newer Python your 12.04 version.

Comment: That is, if I want 2.7.6, I should upgrade Ubuntu?  That actually isn't all that bothersome, since I could just keep Precise on a separate partition.  UPDATE:  For the moment, I just installed Anaconda, which got me a separate installation of 2.7.5.  I will definitely bear this in mind though.  Next time I break everything, I'll start playing with newer releases.

Comment: Yeppers. I also think new versions of things are good.  And these with 'whole OS virtualization' like docker you can even keep another machine _running on the same machine_ without too much.  More bare-bones alternative is libvirt which is in Ubuntu.

Answer (score 5):

removing python from Ubuntu even temporarily will probably irreversibly crash your system.

for handling multiple versions of python and its libraries, check out [python virtualenv](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/virtualenv) or even better [virtualenvwrapper](http://virtualenvwrapper.readthedocs.org/en/latest/)

see a nice article [here](http://www.jontourage.com/2011/02/09/virtualenv-pip-basics/)

Comment: "removing python from Ubuntu even temporarily will probably irreversibly crash your system."  As mentioned, I just learned this from first hand experience.  Reading up on virtualenv, thanks for the link!